# problemas al instalar laravel

Tags: composer

Buen dia estaba navegando en github y descarge un proyecto mismo instale el composer update y todo bien el problema fue que al instalar el composer normal me manda el siguiente error

[image: 1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si notas en los mensajes te dice claro que tu versión de PHP es inferior a la que se requiere para que esos paquetes funcionen, entonces tus soluciones son: o actualizas tu PHP o usas una versión inferior de dichos paquetes

Comment: acavo de dejar una imagen de la version de mi php

Comment: Por eso amigo en el mensaje dice que requieres PHP 7.4 *idealmente* pues el segundo paquete requiere al menos PHP 7.3 y tu tienes PHP 7.2, la solución sigue siendo lo que te dije

Comment: ya me salio este error----

  [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl ex
  tension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-install

Comment: ers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

Comment: Abre tu php.ini y habilita esa opción, esta comentada y no funciona por eso el mensaje de error